# How do I create a multi step form using reduxForms?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I need to create a tabbed multi step form with validation where data from one tab needs to be carried forward to the next. The user should be able to go back and edit the form in the previous tab.. How do I create one using reduxForms or any other method?

Comment: Have a look here: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/wizard/

Answer (score 7):

In redux-form its call `Wizard Form`. Here is the api and example [api](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/wizard/)